# Toggling the visibility of personal notes within a paragraph

Tags: comments

In a LaTeX document I'm writing, I'm using the Comment package to write personal notes that I can enable and disable at will, as in the next example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{note_text}{rgb}{0.7,0,0}
\usepackage{comment}
\specialcomment{note}{\begingroup\color{note_text}}{\endgroup}
% Uncomment the next line for public version without personal notes
%\excludecomment{note}

\begin{document}

This is a serious sentence.

\begin{note}
This is a personal note
\end{note}

\end{document}
```

Then by toggling between `\excludecomment{note}` and `%\excludecomment{note}` in the preamble, I can choose whether the document includes my personal notes or not. So far, so good.

Now comes my question: how can I do something similar with inline text within a paragraph? I would like to do something like the following:

```
This is a serious \note{(or not??)} sentence.
```

But of course that doesn't work as "note" has been defined as an environment through the `\specialcomment` command. So, is there any way I can use the Comment package to do this? Or some other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
\newif\ifmynotes
\mynotestrue

\definecolor{notetext}{rgb}{0.7,0,0}
\def\mynote#1{\ifmynotes\textcolor{notetext}{#1}\else\fi}
```

With the usage `\mynote{This ia a note}`.
And if you want to hide your notes, you write `\mynotesfalse`.

Comment: you might want to add an `\ignorespaces` between `\else` and `\fi`. Otherwise, you will have two spaces with `\mynotesfalse`.

Comment: This rocks, thanks! There's only a minor problem left, which I haven't been able to fix with @jakun's `\ignorespaces`. What if I have the inline comment in front of a punctutation mark, like `This is a serious sentence\note{ (or not??)}.`? Ideally, I'd like it to appear as either "This is a serious sentence." or "This is a serious sentence (or not??)." But I'm finding it tricky to get the space before the parenthesis when notes are enabled.

Comment: @ÁngelJoséRiesgo replace `\ignorespaces` with `\unskip`. `\ignorespaces` eats up following spaces, `\unskip` eats up preceding spaces. (At first I thought it wouldn't matter which one to use here, but it seems I did not think far enough. Good point.)

Comment: Thanks, @jakun. That's great; it now works perfectly. I can now write 'This is a serious sentence \note{(or not??)}.' and the whitespace after "sentence" vanishes when disabling the notes.